# count of teachers and students for each subject

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables, `user_table` to classify as a teacher or student, `subject_table` to mention different subject, and `enrolled_table` stating who registered as teacher/student and for which subject.

I want to have count of student, teacher count for each subject!

**user_table**

```
user_id | user_name | contact_no | password | flag
      6 | Abhis     |  123456788 |      123 | s
      5 | Abhish    |  123456789 |      123 | s
      8 | Sneha     | 1111111111 |      123 | s
      7 | Snehil    | 1111112222 |      123 | s
      1 | Narsingh  | 1234567890 |      123 | t
      2 | Abhinav   | 1234567891 |     1234 | t
      3 | Abhi      | 1234567892 |      123 | s
      4 | Abhishek  | 1234567893 |      123 | s
```

**subject_table**

```
sub_id | sub_name 
     3 | CSS
     1 | HTML
     2 | JQUERY
```

**enrolled_table**

```
enr_id | sub_id | user_id | date       | start_time | end_time
     1 |      1 |       1 | 2016-04-01 | 09:00:00   | 10:00:00
     2 |      2 |       1 | 2016-04-01 | 10:00:00   | 11:00:00
     3 |      3 |       1 | 2016-04-01 | 11:00:00   | 12:00:00
     4 |      1 |       5 | 2016-04-01 | 09:00:00   | 10:00:00
     5 |      1 |       6 | 2016-04-01 | 12:00:00   | 13:00:00
     6 |      1 |       7 | 2016-04-01 | 12:00:00   | 13:00:00
     7 |      1 |       2 | 2016-04-01 | 13:00:00   | 14:00:00
     8 |      2 |       2 | 2016-04-01 | 13:00:00   | 14:00:00
```

Comment: @m2j, read the question carefully before adding such answers. OP does not need total counts of students or teachers, but count per subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    st.sub_name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ut.flag = 's' THEN 1 END) AS students,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ut.flag = 't' THEN 1 END) AS teachers
FROM
    subject_table st
    INNER JOIN enrolled_table et ON et.sub_id = st.sub_id
    INNER JOIN user_table ut ON ut.user_id = et.user_id
GROUP BY
    st.sub_name
```

Comment: is there an option to limit the count of first 30 students,for a particular subject, in one  time slot , and next 30 for the same subject  for next  time slot  ??